# Remove namespace prefix from WCF SOAP response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am implementing a WCF service to replace an existing SOAP service. The clients that access this service cannot be changed (apart from config to point at new server).

When responding to a method called Ping, the original server responds with:

[image]

Recreating the method with WCF, I have managed to get as close as:

[image]

When I call the original service from a C# console app, the PingResult is populated correctly.  Just changing the address of the endpoint to my new service and rerunning, the service returns the new response, but the PingResult is null. The only thing I can see that's different between the original and mine is the "ns1" prefix on the PingResult node.  Which I am guessing is tripping up the deserialization at the client end.

So my question is, how can I remove the ns1 prefix from PingResult?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you mock the service, return a literal string of xml without the namespace and see if the client can deserialize it?

Comment: @Crowcoder That is exactly what I'm working through now, cheers.

Comment: @Crowcoder Sending a string of xml with the namespace prefix removed is deserialized just perfectly by the client.  If there is a point in the wcf workflow where I can edit the xml before it's sent, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, I've never altered the message before so I'm not sure if it works exactly like this but I have done this to log the message.

Implement a message listener. You have the opportunity to handle the `BeforeSendReply` method where you have access to the message and the ability to alter it.

Then decorate your contract implementation class with the attribute `[MessageListenerBehavior]`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class MessageListenerBehavior : Attribute, IDispatchMessageInspector, IServiceBehavior
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {

            Message msg = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue).CreateMessage();

            try
            {
                //Setup StringWriter to use as input for our StreamWriter
                //This is needed in order to capture the body of the message, because the body is streamed.
                using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                using (XmlWriter xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
                {
                    msg.WriteMessage(xmlTextWriter);
                    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                    xmlTextWriter.Close();

                    string thexml = stringWriter.ToString();

                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(thexml);
                    // alter the doc here...........
                       Message newMsg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "http://..something", doc.ToString());

                reply = newMsg;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { //handle it }
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                foreach (var endpoint in dispatcher.Endpoints)
                {
                    endpoint.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MessageListenerBehavior());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class WcfMessgeLoggerExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(MessageListenerBehavior);
            }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new MessageListenerBehavior();
        }
    }
}
```

When you do `Message.CreateMessage` I don't know how much the `Action` parameter matters in the reply, but you can read about how to build it's value:

[Use the Actionproperty to control the action of the method's input message. Because WCF uses this action to dispatch an incoming message to the appropriate method, messages used within a contract operation must have unique actions. The default action value is a combination of the contract namespace (the default value is "http://tempuri.org/"), the contract name (interface name or the class name, if no explicit service interface is used), the operation name, and an additional string ("Response") if the message is a correlated response. You can override this default with the Action property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

> Update

I also have these items in `system.serviceModel` config:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MessageListenerBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  ...

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MessageListenerBehavior" name="... your service name...">
```

...

Comment: Accepted as answer as it does answer the question above, but in the end I didn't need to do any of this as I regenerated the server from the client's wsdl which fixed all of the issues I was having trying to replicate. Thanks!